# How do I blur out my UIViewController with some layer ontop (not code, just concept)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I was using the AirBnB app today and I really liked their UX when they log someone in.

they have the a normal login view and when you hit 'Submit' or whatever to kick off the auth process, they then put a black layer on top, semi opaque and it has a spinning animation.

what are the technical terms to describe this?

what are the objects they probably used? I want to give this a go myself, but I'm only R&D'ing so I'm not going to spend time doing hardcore low level graphics. Just a quick n dirty concept.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There is now a category to UIImage provided by Apple called UIImage+ImageEffects that can speed up these tricks. You then just call one of the methods to apply the effect. It is however always good to shrink down the image resolution before the call, as it takes some time to compute.

- (UIImage *)applyLightEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyExtraLightEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyDarkEffect;
- (UIImage *)applyTintEffectWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor;

https://github.com/codeschool/UIImage-ImageEffects

[https://github.com/iGriever/TWSReleaseNotesView/blob/master/TWSReleaseNotesView/UIImage%2BImageEffects.h](https://github.com/iGriever/TWSReleaseNotesView/blob/master/TWSReleaseNotesView/UIImage+ImageEffects.h)

To take an image as displayed on the screen:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageView.bounds.size, self.imageView.opaque, 0.0);
[self.imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImage *blurredImage = [img applyDarkEffect];
```

Apple's session on this: [WWDC 2013 Session 226: Implementing Engaging UI on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/), page 40 of the PDF or around 15:00 of the video. They explain it there in detail.

Comment: very interesting! I've really really new to this. Can you please comment each line above, with what you are trying to do? Please?

Comment: I have added second link as it seems the are more versions of the category around. You don't have to do the shrinking or playing with the UIGraphicsImageContext, but as I said, the blur computation takes some time and if you send a full res picture it takes several seconds. If you only intend to display it on a screen, then it is good to shrink the image down to a screen resolution prior the effect. Or you can use this code above to actual read the image currantle displayed from a context, which is like a scratchpad. I will edit the post to include Apple's session on this.

Answer (score 0):

Take an image of the view that you want to blur and apply a blur transform to the image. Then, add the modified image to your view and place whatever other view you want on top.

Technically, this would be done using Core Image (`CIGaussianBlur`).

Comment: can you control the z index of objects you place on a view? so if i have an `Image View` object on my view, can i make that hidden .. and then when i put an image inside it, make it 'on top' of all the other objects on in the view (like the username/password/signin) ?

Comment: You can control where you add subviews and reorder the subviews (like using `bringSubviewToFront:`)...

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries out there, that can help you:

- https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView
- https://github.com/relatedcode/ProgressHUD